# Plotting the first moon of the month

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created an example drawing.
To create a crescent moon at the beginning of the month I had to create one circle on top of the other circle. The upper circle hides the entire part of the moon that is not visible at the beginning of the month.
My problem is this:
The reality is that the center of the illuminated part of the moon always faces the center of the sun.
I don't know how to draw it.
For example: the azimuth of the sun at sunset is: 180 degrees and the altitude is 0 degrees. The azimuth of the moon at this time is also 180 degrees but at an altitude of 10 degrees so the moon is looking down at the sun.
On the other hand, when the moon is at azimuth 150 it looks diagonally towards the sun, down and to the right.
I would be very grateful if someone could help fix the code so that whenever I change the azimuth of the sun, the illuminated part of the moon will change accordingly and always face the direction of the sun.
Thank you!

I created an example drawing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge


# Set the coordinates for Jerusalem
longitude = 35.2137  # Jerusalem's longitude
latitude = 31.7683  # Jerusalem's latitude

# Set the time for the observation
observation_time = '19:00'  # Time in HH:MM format

# Set the positions of the sun and the moon
sun_altitude = 0  # Sun's altitude in degrees
sun_azimuth = 280  # Sun's azimuth in degrees
moon_altitude = 30  # Moon's altitude in degrees
moon_azimuth = 280  # Moon's azimuth in degrees
#moon_azimuth = 265  # Moon's azimuth in degrees

# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Set the background color
background_color = "lightblue"
fig.patch.set_facecolor(background_color)
ax.set_facecolor(background_color)


# Set the x-axis limits to represent the western horizon
ax.set_xlim(sun_azimuth-30, sun_azimuth+30)
ax.set_ylim(0, 40)

radius = 5

# Plot the sun and the moon
sun_center = (sun_azimuth, sun_altitude)
sun_circle = Circle(sun_center, radius, color='orange')
ax.add_patch(sun_circle)
moon_center = (moon_azimuth, moon_altitude)
moon_circle = Circle(moon_center, radius, color='white')
ax.add_patch(moon_circle)
#moon_bright_center = (moon_azimuth-0.5, moon_altitude+0.5) # if moon_azimuth == 265 and sun_azimuth == 280
moon_bright_center = (moon_azimuth, moon_altitude+0.8) # if moon_azimuth == 280 and sun_azimuth == 280
moon_bright = Circle(moon_bright_center, radius+0.5, color=background_color)
ax.add_patch(moon_bright)

# Set the title and labels
ax.set_title(f'Western Horizon in Jerusalem on {observation_time}')
ax.set_xlabel("Azimuth")
ax.set_ylabel("Altitude")
plt.grid()

# Set the aspect ratio to equal
ax.set_aspect('equal')



# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This of course is just a visual rough approximation - not a rigorously scientific, astronomically precise calculated representation. But you could for example try something quite simple like calculating a normalized difference between the moon's with respect to the sun's azimuths, and in turn using the set radius of the moon as a scalar, then shift the second circle you are plotting which effectively mimics the moon shadowing itself.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge

mpl.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16, 10]

# Set the coordinates for Jerusalem
longitude = 35.2137  # Jerusalem's longitude
latitude = 31.7683  # Jerusalem's latitude

# Set the time for the observation
observation_time = "19:00"  # Time in HH:MM format

# Set the positions of the sun and the moon
sun_altitude = 0  # Sun's altitude in degrees
sun_azimuth = 280  # Sun's azimuth in degrees
moon_altitude = 30  # Moon's altitude in degrees
moon_azimuth = 260  # Moon's azimuth in degrees

# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Set the background color
background_color = "lightblue"
fig.patch.set_facecolor(background_color)
ax.set_facecolor(background_color)


# Set the x-axis limits to represent the western horizon
ax.set_xlim(sun_azimuth - 60, sun_azimuth + 60)
ax.set_ylim(0, 40)

radius = 5

# Plot the sun and the moon
sun_center = (sun_azimuth, sun_altitude)
sun_circle = Circle(sun_center, radius, color="orange")
ax.add_patch(sun_circle)

for d in range(sun_azimuth - 45, sun_azimuth + 60, 15):
    moon_azimuth = d
    moon_center = (moon_azimuth, moon_altitude)
    moon_circle = Circle(moon_center, radius, color="white")
    ax.add_patch(moon_circle)

    az_d = (moon_azimuth - sun_azimuth) / 360
    moon_bright_center = (
        moon_azimuth + az_d * radius,
        moon_altitude + 0.8,
    )
    moon_bright = Circle(
        moon_bright_center, radius + 0.5, color=background_color
    )
    ax.add_patch(moon_bright)

# Set the title and labels
ax.set_title(f"Western Horizon in Jerusalem on {observation_time}")
ax.set_xlabel("Azimuth")
ax.set_ylabel("Altitude")
plt.grid()

# Set the aspect ratio to equal
ax.set_aspect("equal")

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

for example, gives:
[image: Matplotlib plot showing rough approximation of shadowing of moon with respect to its angle relative to the sun]

The altitude is not taken into account here, but, that is probably acceptable. It would only contribute a difference which already is below the limit of precision of the other positional calculations, etc. As far as I understand (e.g., [See wikipedia on "Moon Illusion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_illusion) - and there is much else written about similar known-since-ancient-times illusory perceptions with regards to the moon's apparent altitude from observers on earth).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the position of the illuminated part of the moon based on the azimuth of the sun. To achieve this, you'll need to calculate new coordinates for the illuminated part of the moon so that it always faces the direction of the sun. Here's how you can do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge

# ... (your existing code here)

# Calculate the angle between the sun and the moon
angle_difference = moon_azimuth - sun_azimuth

# Calculate the new position of the bright part of the moon
moon_bright_azimuth = moon_azimuth - angle_difference
moon_bright_center = (moon_bright_azimuth, moon_altitude + 0.8)
moon_bright = Circle(moon_bright_center, radius + 0.5, color=background_color)
ax.add_patch(moon_bright)

# ... (your existing code here)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

In this code, we calculate the difference between the azimuths of the sun and the moon, and then use this difference to calculate a new azimuth for the illuminated part of the moon. This allows you to create a visualization where the illuminated part of the moon always faces the sun.

EDITED: I apologize for the misunderstanding. It seems like you need a more complex transformation to accurately adjust the position of the illuminated part of the moon based on the azimuth of the sun. Here's a more detailed approach that takes into account the movement of the upper circle of the moon:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge

# ... (your existing code here)

# Calculate the angle between the sun and the moon
angle_difference = np.radians(moon_azimuth - sun_azimuth)

# Calculate the new position of the bright part of the moon
moon_bright_azimuth = moon_azimuth
moon_bright_altitude = moon_altitude + 0.8 * np.sin(angle_difference)
moon_bright_center = (moon_bright_azimuth, moon_bright_altitude)
moon_bright = Circle(moon_bright_center, radius + 0.5, color=background_color)
ax.add_patch(moon_bright)

# ... (your existing code here)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

This code snippet calculates the angle difference between the sun and the moon in radians and then uses trigonometric functions to adjust the altitude of the illuminated part of the moon based on the azimuth difference. This should result in a more accurate representation where the illuminated part of the moon faces the direction of the sun. I hope this will help solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it doesn't work for me. Note that the moon consists of two circles that sit one above the other, and you need to move the upper circle not only to the right or left but also up or down, and you need to move the two parameters in an appropriate ratio.

Comment: Thanks a lot for contributing with an elaborate answer to StackOverflow! I would suggest that you integrate your edited section into the main section of your answer for easier readability.